# SSIS Package Failing Login Failed

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

*Context: User foo has access to both the server its running on and the server its targeting with the package.*

> Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005
>   Description: "The metadata could not be determined because every code
>   path results in an error; see previous errors for some of these.".  An
>   OLE DB record is available.   Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native
>   Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Login failed for user
>   "foo"

I have verified the password and I also have it set to `DoNotSaveSensitive` for the `Protection Level`.  I am referencing an AD service account, which I am running it under.  I have pulled it into Visual Studio and get the same result.

Interestingly enough I have two packages within the same project and one runs while the other will not.

Comment: I'm a little confused.  You verified the password, but set to DoNotSaveSensative (which doesn't save passwords), and are using an AD Service Account (which shouldn't have the password in the package anyway).   Also could you be running into something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35951765/the-metadata-could-not-be-determined-because-every-code-path-results-in-an-error